# Forcing games to run in exclusive fullscreen mode (for nVidia Share/GameStream)

Tags: graphics-card, monitor, streaming

nVidia Share requires games to be run in exclusive fullscreen mode (it cannot be borderless windowed) to be able to work.

Is there a way for me to force games without the option to run in exclusive fullscreen mode?

The game in particular that I'm interested in doing this is Gang Beasts because it has local but no online multiplayer support (nVidia Share solves that problem). It would be great if there were a general solution though because I tried and noticed that quite a few other games I was interested in also did not have the option of exclusive fullscreen mode.

Comment: A GameStream update in 2014 allowed for windowed capture. Why are you using Share and not GameStream?

Comment: I do not have a Shield, the point is to play local multiplayer with friends on my PC, over the net. That requires nVidia Share.

Well if a GameStream update allowed that though, I guess Share might follow suit soon?